# Using VBA to remove excess comma rows from a recently converted .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, txt

I currently extract a file from a source system and I get a .csv file. My process requires me to save this .csv as a .txt file so it can be uploaded to another system.

I have written VBA code which does this automatically for a list of .csv files.

However, the .txt files have lots of empty rows (denoted as commas) underneath the data. I have checked this and it is not real data, i.e., there are no spaces here. I am assuming it is a sort of metadata. But it is causing me problems as I need to remove all the bottom commas before it can be uploaded.

Here is an example of what my .txt file look like after being converted from .csv:

```
File name,dim1,blank,dim2
file 1,1,,apple
file 1,2,,orange
file 1,3,,banana
,,
,,
,,
,,
```

I need it to look like this:

```
File name,dim1,blank,dim2
file 1,1,,apple
file 1,2,,orange
file 1,3,,banana
```

I am aware of this answer here. But this doesn't solve the problem as I am left with no commas but empty space below the data so it can't be used as an upload.

```
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(FolderPath & FileName & ".txt")
    If fn = "" Then Exit Sub
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = ",+$"
        Open Replace(fn, ".txt", "_Clean.txt") For Output As #1
            Print #1, .Replace(txt, "")
        Close #1
    End With
```

The end result would then look like this which is not suitable:

```
File name,dim1,blank,dim2
file 1,1,,apple
file 1,2,,orange
file 1,3,,banana
```

Here is the code which creates the .txt files from the source .csv files. I am not tied to this approach so happy to change if it removes the commas

```
Sub CreateTextFiles()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A4")
Dim FileName As String
Dim FolderPath As String
FolderPath = Range("C1").Value

For Each cell In rng
    FileName = cell.Value
    'THIS WORKS BUT THE COMMAS ARE STILL PRESENT
    FileCopy FolderPath & FileName & ".csv", FolderPath & FileName & ".txt"
    
    'OPENS A NOTEPAD
    'Shell "notepad.exe " & FolderPath & FileName & ".csv", vbNormalFocus
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Text files have been created"
End Sub
```

Comment: What difference is between what follows after "I need it to look like this:" and after "The end result would then look like this which is not suitable:"? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: removed trailing newline from last output line.

Here's one way you could do it:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    ProcessCSV "C:\Temp\Test.csv"

End Sub

Sub ProcessCSV(f As String)
    Dim fso As Object, strmIn As Object, strmOut As Object, l As String
    Dim col As New Collection, i As Long
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    'open input and output streams
    Set strmIn = fso.OpenTextFile(Filename:=f, IOMode:=1)
    Do While Not strmIn.AtEndOfStream 'loop through the input file lines
        l = strmIn.ReadLine
        If Len(Replace(l, ",", "")) > 0 Then col.Add l 'save line if not just commas
    Loop
    strmIn.Close   'close stream
    
    Set strmOut = fso.OpenTextFile(Filename:=Replace(f, ".csv", "_clean.txt", Compare:=vbTextCompare), _
                                   IOMode:=2, Create:=True)
    For i = 1 To col.Count - 1
        strmOut.WriteLine col(i)  'write all lines except last
    Next i
    strmOut.Write col(col.Count)  'last line with no newline
    strmOut.Close                 'close stream
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer is works. One more requirement I have realized is that the resulting text file cannot have a line below the data. It literally just needs a backspace before it is saved. It's such a small detail but my imports will not work otherwise. I have tried `Selection.TypeBackspace` & `SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")` But I can't get it to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Code updated above...

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Sub CSVtoTXT()

    ' select csv file
    Dim csvFile As String, txtFile As String
    Dim fso, tsIn, tsOut, s As String, n As Long, i As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .InitialFileName = ""
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "csv", "*.csv"
        .Title = "Select csv"
        
        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "File not selected to import."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        csvFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        txtFile = Replace(csvFile, ".csv", ".txt")
    End With
    
    ' remove `` lines
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set tsOut = fso.createtextfile(txtFile)
    Set tsIn = fso.opentextfile(csvFile)
    With tsIn
        Do While .AtEndOfStream = False
           s = .readline
           If Left(s, 1) <> "," Then
               n = n + 1
               If n > 1 Then s = vbCrLf & s
               tsOut.write s
           End If
           i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    
    ' result
    MsgBox i & " lines read from " & csvFile & vbLf & _
           n & " lines written to " & txtFile, vbInformation
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for your solution. Although I used the answer above, this was tested and also works. One final requirement I have realized is that the resulting text file cannot have a line below the data. It literally just needs a backspace before it is saved. It's such a small detail but my imports will not work otherwise. I have tried Selection.TypeBackspace & SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}") But I can't get it to work properly. Any solutions?

Comment: @JackPennington OK see update

Answer (score 0):

Below is modified version of your VBA code, please try.

```
Sub CreateTextFiles()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A4")
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    FolderPath = Range("C1").Value
    
    For Each cell In rng
        FileName = cell.Value
        Set ws = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName & ".csv").Sheets(1)
        
        For LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If Trim(ws.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value) <> "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next LastRow
        
        'Delete all rows below the last non-empty row
        If LastRow < ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Then
            ws.Rows(LastRow + 1 & ":" & ws.Rows.Count).Delete
        End If
        
        ws.SaveAs FolderPath & FileName & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText
        ws.Parent.Close
        
    Next cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Text files have been created"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Update the `RegExp` pattern and eliminate trailing carriage return
- Modified code is marked w/ **

```
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(FolderPath & Filename & ".txt")
    If fn = "" Then Exit Sub
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "^,+$\s*"  ' **
        Dim sNewTxt As String  ' **
        Open Replace(fn, ".txt", "_Clean.txt") For Output As #1
        sNewTxt = .Replace(txt, "") ' **
        sNewTxt = Left(sNewTxt, Len(sNewTxt) - 2) ' **
        Print #1, sNewTxt ' **
        Close #1
    End With
```